# How to create a report in SharePoint that would sort/group several entries in a list together

Tags: reporting-services, reports, reporting

I am trying to create a printable report that takes several entries in a list and groups them together. My company is moving equipment that we have inventoried and we want to have a print out for each desk that shows all the equipment assigned to that desk. We currently do it in access but we are looking for a SharePoint solution. I need a report that filters the list by a move group and then groups the equipment assigned to each cube into a print out that we can put on the desk. Does anyone know how this can be done? We are even willing to go to a 3rd party app if necessary.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server? You can create printable reports using SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) that gets data from a SharePoint list.

Comment: Is your data in an Access Database? You should consider migrating it either to SharePoint or SQL Server, then you will have some options available

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is connect your SharePoint list with Excel and generate reports (Matrix, Pie or chart) report which you can also take a print out.

Steps we follow in general

- Open new Excel worksheet
- Go to "Data" tab
- Click "New Query" from ribbon
- Go to "From Other Sources" -> Select "From SharePoint List"
- Select your SharePoint list
- "Load" data
- You can create pivot tables from the data loaded onto SharePoint.

This approach has been tested with SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint online.

Let me know if you still need additional information.